# Find volume of $A=\{(x,y,z): 4x^2+y^2<4,x>0,x^2>z>0\}$. Review solution.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I need to find volume of $A=\{(x,y,z): 4x^2+y^2<4,x>0,x^2>z>0\}$
So we need to count following integral: $\int\int\int_A1dxdyzdz$

First, we see that $x<1$ because $4x^2+y^2<4$.

So $\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}\int_0^{4-4x^2}1dydzdx=\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}(4-4x^2)dzdx=\int_0^14x^2(x^2-1)dx$

Is it correct?

Comment: Integration is over $y$, not $y^2$, so must be: $\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-4x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-4x^2}}1dydzdx$

Comment: @RafaBudría Well, that look much more complicated. Is there better way to solve this?

Comment: I don't see any way to make the result simpler. Where the problem come from?

Comment: @RafaBudría I had limited experience with integration, so sometimes easy integrals look difficult to me. This is part of my homework. Final integral is $4\int_0^1 x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. You are doing it well. The integral can be perfectly done, but it needs some work (I think the variable change $x=sin(t)$ simplifies). I've used wolfram alpha and returns $\pi/16$